# Term to mean a different person conjugation?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Recently, someone said the following, in a chat room:
"You're an adult and that means it's your turn to decide what that means."

I knew that came from something I recognized, and it turns out it is referring to [this xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/150/), which instead says "we're grownups now, and it's our turn to decide what that means".

I was trying to explain to someone I was talking to via voice that they had quoted that comic, but I couldn't find a way to easily convey the shift from the original comic's use of first person plural, and the chatter's use of second person singular. Is there a word or phrase that easily denotes that shift?

Comment: @johnlawler I think *this* question is one that you could probably answer off the top of your head.  It was asked by a friend of mine, so I'd like to enlist your help for her sake.

Comment: No, there's no term, really. They used, as you said, second person instead of first person plural. In speech it probly would be simpler to just quote both sentences, so your addressee could do their own comparison. If they cared. If they even listened; most people are not interested in grammar. Trust me on this.

Comment: In this case, the person was interested, and that was where I started wondering...

Comment: It's just a different "take" on it.

Comment: "To adapt a quote, 'You're an adult and that means it's your turn to decide what that means'." Of course, there's adapting, and then there's misquoting.

Comment: Robbed by @EdwinAshworth once again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to describe how the speaker changed the quote by changing the first person pronoun to a second person pronoun, you would say that they **changed the grammatical person** of the subject of the original quote.

In this case, they also **changed the grammatical number**, by moving from a plural pronoun ("we") to a numerically ambiguous pronoun ("you") that in context is acting as a singular pronoun (because it must agree in number with the singular article "an" in the noun phrase "an adult").